Why does my Bayesian linear regression with survival analysis perform worse than standard linear regression?
Experts in statistics wanted here.
I am working on a Bayesian linear regression function that considers asymmetric uncertainties and censored data (upper/lower limits) in both x and y. The function uses the emcee MCMC package to estimate the posterior distributions of the slope and intercept. Despite taking into account these complexities, I find that a simple linear regression (done with scipy’s stats.linregress) or a basic Bayesian linear regression using emcee without considering the uncertainties and limits performs better on simulated data.
My function:
def bayesian_linear_regression_survival_analysis(x, y, xerr_low, xerr_high, yerr_low, yerr_high, m_guess, d_guess, nwalkers=8, nsteps=int(0.5e4)):
    """
    Perform Bayesian linear regression considering asymmetric uncertainties and censored data in both x and y.
    """

    def model(theta, x):
        slope, intercept = theta
        return slope * x + intercept

    def survival_function(observed_value, model_value, sigma):
        """ Survival function for censored data. Returns the probability of observing data above (for lower limits) or below (for upper limits) the given value. """
        return stats.norm.sf(observed_value, loc=model_value, scale=sigma)
    
    def estimate_sigma(limit_value, model_value, fixed_sigma=1e-6):
        # Calculate the sigma as the absolute difference between the limit value and the model value
        sigma = np.abs(limit_value - model_value)
        # Ensure that the sigma is not an array with ambiguous truth values
        sigma = np.where(sigma > 0, sigma, fixed_sigma)
        return sigma

    def log_likelihood(theta, x, y, xerr_low, xerr_high, yerr_low, yerr_high):
        slope, intercept = theta
        model_line = model(theta, x)

        sigma_x = estimate_sigma(x, model_line)
        sigma_y = estimate_sigma(y, model_line)

        # Weight sigma_x and sigma_y based on the relative contributions of the lower and upper errors
        weight_x = np.where(x > model_line, xerr_high / (xerr_high + xerr_low), xerr_low / (xerr_high + xerr_low))
        weighted_sigma_x = weight_x * sigma_x

        weight_y = np.where(y > model_line, yerr_high / (yerr_high + yerr_low), yerr_low / (yerr_high + yerr_low))
        weighted_sigma_y = weight_y * sigma_y

        # Calculate the total variance, including the contribution from sigma_x and sigma_y
        point_variance = weighted_sigma_y**2 + (slope * weighted_sigma_x)**2

        # Calculate the residuals between observed data and the model prediction
        residuals = y - model_line
        
        # Calculate weights based on how much the errors contribute to the point variance
        weight = (weighted_sigma_y**2 + (slope * weighted_sigma_x)**2) / point_variance
        
        # Calculate the weighted log-likelihood
        log_likelihood = -0.5 * np.sum(weight * ((residuals)**2 / point_variance + np.log(point_variance)))

        # Apply survival function for censored data (upper/lower limits)
        for i in range(len(x)):
            if xerr_low[i] == 0:  # Lower limit on x
                sigma_x_i = estimate_sigma(x[i], model_line[i])
                log_likelihood += np.log(survival_function(x[i], model_line[i], sigma_x_i) + 1e-10)
            if xerr_high[i] == 0:  # Upper limit on x
                sigma_x_i = estimate_sigma(x[i], model_line[i])
                log_likelihood += np.log(survival_function(x[i], model_line[i], sigma_x_i) + 1e-10)
            if yerr_low[i] == 0:  # Lower limit on y
                sigma_y_i = estimate_sigma(y[i], model_line[i])
                log_likelihood += np.log(survival_function(y[i], model_line[i], sigma_y_i) + 1e-10)
            if yerr_high[i] == 0:  # Upper limit on y
                sigma_y_i = estimate_sigma(y[i], model_line[i])
                log_likelihood += np.log(survival_function(y[i], model_line[i], sigma_y_i) + 1e-10)
        return log_likelihood

    def log_prior(theta):
        slope, intercept = theta
        if -10.0 < slope < 10.0 and -10.0 < intercept < 10.0:
            return 0.0
        return -np.inf

    def log_probability(theta, x, y, xerr_low, xerr_high, yerr_low, yerr_high):
        lp = log_prior(theta)
        if not np.isfinite(lp):
            return -np.inf
        return lp + log_likelihood(theta, x, y, xerr_low, xerr_high, yerr_low, yerr_high)

    initial = np.array([m_guess, d_guess])
    ndim = 2
    sampler = emcee.EnsembleSampler(nwalkers, ndim, log_probability, args=(x, y, xerr_low, xerr_high, yerr_low, yerr_high))
    pos = initial + 1e-4 * np.random.randn(nwalkers, ndim)
    sampler.run_mcmc(pos, nsteps, progress=True)
    samples = sampler.get_chain(discard=100, thin=15, flat=True)

    return samples, sampler

Example Usage:
To keep this post concise, I will add an example later, but the function is tested on simulated data that includes asymmetric errors and randomly assigned upper/lower limits.
Issue:
When I compare the results of this function with a standard linear regression (using scipy.stats.linregress) or a basic Bayesian linear regression using emcee, I find that those simpler methods often outperform my survival analysis approach. This is unexpected, as my function should theoretically handle uncertainties and limits better.
Question:
Could there be an issue with my approach to calculating the log-likelihood or how I handle the uncertainties and limits? Any advice or insights would be greatly appreciated.
Full code:
nwalkers, nsteps = 8, int(1e4)

# Initialize random data
# np.random.seed(42)
N = 20
x = np.random.uniform(0, 10, N)
true_slope = 2
true_intercept = 5
y = true_slope * x + true_intercept + np.random.normal(0, 3, N)

# True values for comparison
x_truth = np.arange(-1, 12, 0.2)
y_truth = x_truth * true_slope + true_intercept

# Initialize errors
yerr_low = np.random.uniform(0.5, 3.0, N)
yerr_upp = np.random.uniform(0.5, 3.0, N)
xerr_low = np.random.uniform(0.1, 3.0, N)
xerr_upp = np.random.uniform(0.1, 3.0, N)

large_error_threshold_x = 2.5  
large_error_threshold_y = 4.0  

# Identify indices where the errors exceed the threshold
upper_limit_indices_x = np.where(xerr_upp > large_error_threshold_x)[0]
lower_limit_indices_x = np.where(xerr_low > large_error_threshold_x)[0]
upper_limit_indices_y = np.where(yerr_upp > large_error_threshold_y)[0]
lower_limit_indices_y = np.where(yerr_low > large_error_threshold_y)[0]

# Remove indices from lower limits that are already in upper limits
lower_limit_indices_x = np.setdiff1d(lower_limit_indices_x, upper_limit_indices_x)
lower_limit_indices_y = np.setdiff1d(lower_limit_indices_y, upper_limit_indices_y)

# Apply the upper and lower limits
y[upper_limit_indices_y] += yerr_upp[upper_limit_indices_y]  # Shifted upward for upper limits
y[lower_limit_indices_y] -= yerr_low[lower_limit_indices_y]  # Shifted downward for lower limits
x[upper_limit_indices_x] += xerr_upp[upper_limit_indices_x]  
x[lower_limit_indices_x] -= xerr_low[lower_limit_indices_x] 

# Set yerr_low to 0 for upper limits and yerr_upp to 0 for lower limits in y, same for x
yerr_low[upper_limit_indices_y] = 0
yerr_upp[lower_limit_indices_y] = 0
xerr_low[upper_limit_indices_x] = 0
xerr_upp[lower_limit_indices_x] = 0

# Perform standard linear regression
standard_slope, standard_intercept, _, _, _ = stats.linregress(x, y)

# Perform standard Bayesian linear regression using emcee
def log_likelihood(theta, x, y):
    slope, intercept = theta
    model_line = slope * x + intercept
    sigma2 = np.var(y)
    return -0.5 * np.sum((y - model_line) ** 2 / sigma2 + np.log(sigma2))

def log_prior(theta):
    slope, intercept = theta
    if -10.0 < slope < 10.0 and -10.0 < intercept < 10.0:
        return 0.0
    return -np.inf

def log_probability(theta, x, y):
    lp = log_prior(theta)
    if not np.isfinite(lp):
        return -np.inf
    return lp + log_likelihood(theta, x, y)

initial = np.array([standard_slope, standard_intercept])
ndim = 2
sampler = emcee.EnsembleSampler(nwalkers, ndim, log_probability, args=(x, y))
pos = initial + 1e-4 * np.random.randn(nwalkers, ndim)
sampler.run_mcmc(pos, nsteps, progress=True)
emcee_samples = sampler.get_chain(discard=100, thin=15, flat=True)

emcee_median_slope = np.median(emcee_samples[:, 0])
emcee_median_intercept = np.median(emcee_samples[:, 1])
emcee_slope_percentiles = np.percentile(emcee_samples[:, 0], [16, 84])
emcee_intercept_percentiles = np.percentile(emcee_samples[:, 1], [16, 84])

# Perform Bayesian linear regression with survival analysis
samples, sampler = bayesian_linear_regression_survival_analysis(
    x, y, xerr_low, xerr_upp, yerr_low, yerr_upp, standard_slope, standard_intercept, nwalkers, nsteps)

survival_median_slope = np.median(samples[:, 0])
survival_median_intercept = np.median(samples[:, 1])
survival_slope_percentiles = np.percentile(samples[:, 0], [16, 84])
survival_intercept_percentiles = np.percentile(samples[:, 1], [16, 84])

# Plot the data and the regression results
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))

# Truth
ax.plot(x_truth, y_truth, color='k', label=f"Truth: $y = ({true_slope:.2f})x + ({true_intercept:.2f})$", ls='--')

# Plot all data points
ax.errorbar(x, y, xerr=[xerr_low, xerr_upp], yerr=[yerr_low, yerr_upp], fmt='o', mfc='silver', color='k', ecolor='silver', elinewidth=1)


# Plot the standard linear regression line
y_plot_standard = standard_slope * x_truth + standard_intercept
ax.plot(x_truth, y_plot_standard, label=f"Lin. Regression Fit: $y = ({standard_slope:.2f})x + ({standard_intercept:.2f})$", color='green')

# Plot the emcee fit line
y_plot_emcee = emcee_median_slope * x_truth + emcee_median_intercept
ax.plot(x_truth, y_plot_emcee, label=f"Emcee Fit: $y = ({emcee_median_slope:.2f})x + ({emcee_median_intercept:.2f})$", color='blue')

# Plot the Bayesian linear regression with survival analysis
y_plot_survival = survival_median_slope * x_truth + survival_median_intercept
ax.plot(x_truth, y_plot_survival, color='red', label=f"Survival Analysis Fit: $y = ({survival_median_slope:.2f})x + ({survival_median_intercept:.2f})$")

# Fill between 1-sigma for survival analysis
y_lower = survival_slope_percentiles[0] * x_truth + survival_intercept_percentiles[0]
y_upper = survival_slope_percentiles[1] * x_truth + survival_intercept_percentiles[1]
# ax.fill_between(x_truth, y_lower, y_upper, color='tab:red', alpha=0.3, label='1-sigma region (Survival)')

ax.set_xlabel("x")
ax.set_ylabel("y")
ax.legend()

# Plot the corner plot for the MCMC samples
fig2 = corner.corner(samples, labels=["Slope", "Intercept"], truths=[survival_median_slope, survival_median_intercept],
                     quantiles=[0.16, 0.5, 0.84], show_titles=True, title_fmt=".2f", title_kwargs={"fontsize": 12})

Results:


You might get better advice over at https://stats.stackexchange.com?

Agreed that [stats.SE] is a more appropriate forum for this question. That said, it's not clear what you mean by "performs better"; my advice is to be specific about what is being compared when you say "better". On the face of it, it appears that you are getting nearly the same parameters for ordinary linear regression as for a Bayesian model; that's not too surprising, since the Bayesian model is a generalization of the OLR, and when the uncertainties are small enough, the Bayesian model will reduce to OLR.

You can gauge that by starting with noise-free data and verifying you get the same results. Then increase measurement noise and/or censoring effects. You should find that the posterior distributions become wider and wider, and eventually the posterior mean becomes substantially different. I don't know at what point you'll find that, although I would expect the effect of censoring on the posterior distribution is stronger than the effect of measurement noise.

@RobertDodier for 'better', I mean the model that best represents the original line from where the data were simulated (truth in the image).

Thanks for explaining, Alessandro, but you will have to repeat that when you repost your question on [stats.SE].
